# NetworkManager: connection is down - how to find the reason (admin or failure)?

Tags: networkmanager

I have an ADSL (PPPoE) connection managed by the NetworkManager.

It is configured with autoconnect and infinite retries, but unfortunately the NM is not fully reliable. Sometimes the connection fails and I have to do connection down followed by connection up and then it works again. I made a tiny script that does this automatically.

The only problem is when I want the connection to keep down. In that script I need to detect that the admin did `nmcli c adsl down` and in that case not try a restart.

How could I do that? I have compared the output of `nmcli c show` in both cases, but haven't find anything helpful. The only difference I found is that the NM dispatcher is called with `pre-down` only when bringing down manually, but I'm not sure if I can rely on such detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper script which handles the network up/down and put your keepalive script in there:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDFILE="/tmp/nmclihandler.pid"

#check if pid file exists
if [ -f "$PIDFILE" ]; then
    #check if other process exists
    if [ -d /proc/$(cat "$PIDFILE") ]; then
        echo "killing other instance of script"
        kill $(cat "$PIDFILE")
    #remove pidfile if not
    else
        #echo "removing pidfile"
        rm "$PIDFILE"
    fi
fi
#write pid of current instance to file
echo "$$" > $PIDFILE


keepalive()
{
    #put your current keepalive script here. 
    #It will be run if you pass the --run or -r parameter to the script
    #or if you enable the interface via --up or -u
    echo "keepalive"
}

#command help
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    echo -e "nmcli helper script\n"
    echo -e "Parameter              Desciption\n"
    echo "-h, --help                show this help text"
    echo "-d, --down                disable interface"
    echo "-u, --up              enable interface"
    echo "-r, --run             keepalive connection"
    exit 0
fi

#handle manual network up/down
if [ "$1" == "--down" ] || [ "$1" == "-d" ]; then
    echo "disabling interface"
    nmcli c down adsl
elif [ "$1" == "--up" ] || [ "$1" == "-u" ]; then
    echo "enabling interface"
    nmcli c up adsl
    #run keepalive function after enabling network
elif [ "$1" == "--run" ] || [ "$1" == "-r" ]; then
    #put your keepalive script here
    keepalive
fi
```

The wrapper would only run your keepalive script if `--run` is passed or the adapter gets enabled via `--up`. If `--down` is passed, the network connection gets disabled and the `keepalive()` function will not be run.

Note that this is just a workaround and would not solve the problem if `nmcli` is called directly.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, but it is of little practical help, unfortunately. The admin would need to remember to use a replacement for a standard command. This is equivalent to remembering to stop the keepalive after forcing the connection down. I'm pretty sure the network manager software simply must know the desired state (_should be_ up or down), not only the current state (_is_ up or down or in transition), or else it couldn't manager the interface. I can't just find the way to get that piece of information.

Comment: Maybe you could work with `nmcli con monitor`